# Xprograms over ssh, nothing happens

Tags: xorg, ssh

I'm new to SSH and trying to setup a connection to run Xapplications through my school.
I made the login perfectly fine but once inside, i export the display to my ip ie:

`export DISPLAY=MYIP:0.0`

After that i try to run serveral xapplications for example xterm or firefox, though nothing happens. Instead of telling me that it cant reach the display or similar, I get no responce from the terminal, i have to ctrl + C to get back to the prompt.

I get the feeling I'm missing something simple..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're setting `DISPLAY` then you're overriding `ssh`'s X11 forwarding; `ssh` sets `DISPLAY` properly itself with the `-X` or `-Y` option (you probably want the latter).

Once you connect, run `echo $DISPLAY` , you should see 10:0

Beyond that, your attempt to connect X11 directly (don't do that; it's extremely insecure) is likely being dropped by a firewall.

Also, if you are wanting to tunnel http traffic, rather then forwarding firefox, it is better to use port forwarding, ie a socks proxy.

> ssh -C2qTnN -D 8080 username@server

See: https://calomel.org/firefox_ssh_proxy.html

Comment: If I don't set the display, it tells me "cant open display, display is not set". So how should I not connect to X11 directly? I'm entering ssh -x login@host.

Comment: `ssh` is case sensitive.  `-X` or `-Y` (you want `-Y` as I already told you) turns on X11 forwarding.  `-x` as you gave it turns it *off*.

Comment: Very good, thank you guys! Case sensitivity can be a bitch (when you don't know about it). It now works perfectly fine!